# How to checkout properly with lib2git and C#

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

UPDATE 2: [Update 1 at the end of the post)

I managed to do a checkout finally
That's the good news ;).

The bad news is: It takes 2min 36 sec for a single commit. If I were a user of this program, I would not be waiting that long.....

"git" is, as always a instance of Repository, containing the repo... Next my checkout call:

```
git.Checkout(bss.getCommit(), CheckoutModifiers.Force, (path, completed, total) =>
        { // Update progressbar
            progressBar1.Maximum = total;
            progressBar1.Value = completed;
        }, null);
```

If you need the full source (99% uncommented), please ask and I will put the current version online.... Thanks for your answers :)

Yours,

Florian Reisinger

---

---

---

---

### Original post:

The title says it all ;)
What is working:
I have a *Commit[] steps* full of commits from a repo
I want to checkout the Commit at position "i"
git == Lib2Git Repo

```
git.Checkout(steps[i]);
```

As nothing happend I stopped the program. I do output the number of commits, which went down from 30 to 1.... 
I really need a helping hand...

PS: I do know that there is an overload

```
Checkout(Commit,CheckoutModifiers,CheckoutNotificationOptions, LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.CheckoutProgressHandler)
```

The last thing is a delegate. So the problem, I guess, can be described as "How to use the delegate as well, although I am not sure, that will help with the problem of going down from 30 to 1 commit....

EDIT:

Longer sourcecode. I want to implement bisect GUI using C# and libgit....
Code 1) Getting a Commit[] steps

```
List<BisectStep> bss = new List<BisectStep>();
        ICommitLog commits = git.Branches["master"].Commits;
        foreach (Commit c in commits)
        {
            bss.Add(new BisectStep(c));
        }
        steps = bss.ToArray();
```

In the same method then the Bisect stuff. I made a class BisectStep with the Commit and an int representing an specific value....

```
// Test oldest (Has to be GOOD)
        int i = steps.Length;
        int r = BisectStep.Result.SKIP;
        try
        {
            while (r == BisectStep.Result.SKIP || r == BisectStep.Result.NOTSET)
            {
                i--;
                r = doStep(steps[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        LastKnownWorking = i;
        if (r != BisectStep.Result.GOOD)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem can't be bisected!", "Out of range");
            return;
        }
        r = BisectStep.Result.SKIP;
        i = -1;
        // Test latest (Has to be BAD)
        try
        {
            while (r == BisectStep.Result.SKIP || r == BisectStep.Result.NOTSET)
            {
                i++;
                r = doStep(steps[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        FirstKnownNotWorking = i;
        //Test rest
```

And last but not least the doStep Method

```
 private int doStep(BisectStep bss)
    {
        git.Checkout(bss.getCommit(), CheckoutModifiers.Force, null, null);
        // Checkout
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(new string[] { tb_ondisk.Text, "instdir", "program", "soffice.exe" }));
         if (System.IO.File.Exists(p.StartInfo.FileName))
            p.Start();
        else
            return BisectStep.Result.SKIP;
        GBS form = new GBS();
        DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
        int result = int.MaxValue;
        while (!p.HasExited)
            MessageBox.Show("Please close LibreOffice to continue!", "Close LibreOffice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        switch (dr)
        {
            case (DialogResult.Yes):
                result = BisectStep.Result.GOOD;
                break;
            case (DialogResult.No):
                result = BisectStep.Result.BAD;
                break;
            case (DialogResult.Ignore):
                result = BisectStep.Result.SKIP;
                break;
        }
        bss.setResult(result);
        return result;
    }
```

The "GBS" is a Win-Form with 3 Buttons (Good, Bad, Skip)

Hope this edit helps just a tiny bit ;)

Comment: "As nothing happend" -> What output do you expect? Checkout will replace the content of your working directory with the snapshot of the Commit. If you're doing this in in a loop, there are chances only the latest commit will be reflected in your workdir.

Comment: As described in the documentation, by default it does not check out files, but makes the commit the detached head... I can change that with the CheckoutModifiers property. I honestly think, that the problem is, that I can't execute the second command, because I have no ideas of delegates (The last thing is a delegate, asking for "void(int,int,string)" [do not see this as quote, but it asks for that]

Comment: As described in the documentation by default it does not check out files -> Looks like the documentations **[states otherwise](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryExtensions.cs#L266-L271)**.

Comment: Could you please enhance your question by describing what you're doing (a longer piece of code would be nice to get the context) and what you actually expect as an output?

Comment: PS: I want a checkout to overwrite everything. Do I have to delete every folder in there (except of the .git??)

Comment: Calling Checkout with the `CheckoutModifiers.Force` option should checkout the new commit and update the working directory (and overwrite any local changes). What happens after the call to checkout in this case? Is Checkout not checking out the commit (to a detached head) and updating the working directory?

Comment: I am starting a program (binary bisect LibreOffice) and it has the same id as before. I make sure, that the program has exited, before I start the neyt step. How long does it take to checkout? Am I just to quick? Can someone give me a delegate example, which updates a progressbar?. Once it worked quite quick, that was from nothing -> first commit.....

Comment: @Reisi007 "It takes 2min 36 sec for a single commit" -> That's far too long. Could you please log an issue in the LibGit2Sharp issue tracker with a pointer to the repository you've tested this again?

Comment: @nulltoken: Did so: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/623

Comment: @Reisi007 Oh. Thanks. I didn't make the link with this SO question.

Answer (score 4):

Both flavors of the Checkout method will perform the checkout operation. The second flavor of the Checkout method will (with the delegate) will additionally report progress. You can see (a simple) example of this in the Checkout tests https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CheckoutFixture.cs#L391.

**Note:** Would you provide us with some more context, I'd gladly update this to better answer your concerns.